# how to fix github ssh unable to authenticate?

Tags: laravel, github, ssh, github-actions, ssh-keys

I am trying to auto-deploy from github repo to vps server using github actions, and I get the error:

"ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain"

I have tried changing file permissions for the keys to 600, and have tried both RSA and ECDSA keys

Any idea what else I can do to resolve this error and get the ssh to work?

Comment: Can you tell us which keys are installed where?  The service initiating the connection needs the private key

Comment: According to the error message, the client tried to authenticate using a key and it failed. Please [edit] your question to describe in detail what key it's supposed to be using and what you did to set it up. It might also be helpful to check the logs on the system that you're connecting to, to see if the ssh server logged the reason why authentication failed.